# Exception while rendering Plot (null at com.androidplot.Plot.renderOnCanvas)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, androidplot

I want to plot engine RPM. Firstly I want to show empty plot with no data. App don't crash but I get endless error on android monitor and I don't see plot. I use Android Plot library.

I confirmed code sample from real-time orientation sensor plot. I read somewhere to add one point to plot to prevent crashing but it doesn't work.

I also found in logcat some other errors before `null pointer exception` but I can't paste it here because is to big data.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getDomainLabelPaint []
```

This is logcat form android monitor (couldn't post all logcat so I posted rest on http://pastebin.com/raw/GLEVRYXe)

```
E/com.androidplot.Plot: Exception while rendering Plot.
E/com.androidplot.Plot: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/com.androidplot.Plot:     at com.androidplot.Plot.renderOnCanvas(Plot.java:776)
E/com.androidplot.Plot:     at com.androidplot.Plot$1.run(Plot.java:344)
E/com.androidplot.Plot:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/com.androidplot.Plot: Exception while rendering Plot
```

Here is snippet from code side:

```
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btnPreSetup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPreSetup);
        btnStartTelemetry = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnStartTel);
        tvRpm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRpm);
        tvLoad = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLoad);
        tvCoolantTemp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCoolantTepm);
        tvSpeed = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSpeed);
        tvAirTemp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTempAirFlow);
        tvThrottle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvThrottle);

        // setup the APR History plot:
        rpmPlotGraph = (XYPlot) view.findViewById(R.id.rpmHistoryPlot);

        rpmSeries = new SimpleXYSeries("RPM");
        rpmSeries.useImplicitXVals();

        rpmSeries.addLast(1, 1000);
        //Ustawienia wykresu
        rpmPlotGraph.setRangeBoundaries(800, 5000, BoundaryMode.FIXED); //TODO: FIX
        rpmPlotGraph.setDomainBoundaries(0, HISTORY_SIZE, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
        rpmPlotGraph.addSeries(rpmSeries,
                new LineAndPointFormatter(
                        Color.rgb(100, 100, 200), null, null, null));
        //aprHistoryPlot.addSeries(pitchHistorySeries, new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(100, 200, 100), null, null, null));
        //aprHistoryPlot.addSeries(rollHistorySeries, new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(200, 100, 100), null, null, null));
        rpmPlotGraph.setDomainStepMode(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL);
        rpmPlotGraph.setDomainStepValue(HISTORY_SIZE / 10);
        rpmPlotGraph.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
        rpmPlotGraph.setDomainLabel("Sample Index");
        rpmPlotGraph.getDomainLabelWidget().pack();
        rpmPlotGraph.setRangeLabel("Angle (Degs)");
        rpmPlotGraph.getRangeLabelWidget().pack();

        rpmPlotGraph.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));
        rpmPlotGraph.setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));
        redrawer = new Redrawer(Arrays.asList(new Plot[]{rpmPlotGraph}), 100, false);
    }
```

And view code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="pl.rychlinski.damian.mobilnatelemetria.BluetoothFragment">
...
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
            style="@style/simple_xy"
            android:id="@+id/rpmHistoryPlot"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            androidPlot.backgroundPaint.color="#000000"
            androidPlot.borderPaint.color="#000000"
            androidplot.renderMode="use_background_thread"
            androidPlot.title="History"
            androidPlot.domainLabel="Domain"
            androidPlot.rangeLabel="Range"
            androidPlot.titleWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
            androidPlot.domainLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.rangeLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.backgroundPaint.color="#000000"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.gridBackgroundPaint.color="#000000"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginTop="20dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft="15dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginBottom="25dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginRight="10dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeOriginLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.domainLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_tick_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.domainOriginLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_tick_label_font_size"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

(Full code is on [github](https://github.com/GarryMoveOut/MobilnaTelemetria))

Answer (score 0):

To start, it looks like you might be using Proguard obfuscation.  If that's the case, this is most likely what's causing the **NoSuchMethodException**; you're using Configurator to dynamically configure your plot from XML, which in turn uses reflection to do it's job.  If the expected names have been obfuscated then it will fail in the above manner.

Try either disabling obfuscation or adding this to your proguard config:

```
-keep class com.androidplot.** {
  public *;
}
```

I wouldnt be surprised if this resolves the NPE issue as well.